# Making an object disappear when no longer visible on screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple ApplePicker prototype in Unity and am having trouble with destroying objects. In my script attached to my basket object I want to put this `if` statement in my `Update()` function which says that if an apple reaches a certain y value (i.e falls out of view), to destroy one of the baskets.

```
if(...) {
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

but I don't know what to put as a condition. can someone help me out? In case it is needed, the apple object has the tag "Apple"

Answer (score 4):

The `transform` variable which is a type of [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) is used to access the position, rotation and scale of any GameObject in the scene.

You would have to use  `if (transform.position.y < someValue)` to see if the position is less than any value or `if (transform.position.y > someValue)` to check if it is more than the value.

```
void Update()
{
    float someValue = 10;
    if (transform.position.y < someValue)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

For rotation and scale, use `transform.localEulerAngles` and `transform.localScale` respectively.

> Am I able to check the position of an apple from a script attached to
>   the basket object, because I need to check the position of the apple
>   not the basket

It's the-same thing. Find apple from your other script, store the reference then perform the-same action above.

```
GameObject apple;

void Start()
{
    //Find apple by tag
    apple = GameObject.FindWithTag("Apple");
}

void Update()
{
    float someValue = 10;
    if (apple.transform.position.y < someValue)
    {
        Destroy(apple);
    }
}
```

There is really a better way to check if object is no longer before destroying it. This removes the need of hard-coding the `someValue` value. Just check for the screen size.

```
GameObject apple;

void Start()
{
    //Find apple bt tag
    apple = GameObject.FindWithTag("Apple");
}

void Update()
{
    if (!IsVisibleOnScreen(apple))
    {
        Destroy(apple);
    }
}

private bool IsVisibleOnScreen(GameObject target)
{
    Camera mainCam = Camera.main;
    Vector3 targetScreenPoint = mainCam.WorldToScreenPoint(target.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center);

    if ((targetScreenPoint.x < 0) || (targetScreenPoint.x > Screen.width) ||
            (targetScreenPoint.y < 0) || (targetScreenPoint.y > Screen.height))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (targetScreenPoint.z < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Am I able to check the position of an apple from a script attached to the basket object, because I need to check the position of the apple not the basket.

Comment: Find the apple and perform the-same action on it. See my edit

Comment: @Franklin Don't forget to accept answer if your problem is solved.